# Specify Output Voltage of a USB Dongle

Tags: usb, power-supply, power-control

I am looking for some device which offers an API to specify the voltage output of an USB port.

So actually I want to give power to some hardware by the USB Port and I want to specify on the PC if I want, for example, 1V or 5V.

Somehow google results only in devices to measure the amperage of the usb port.

I hope it is somehow understandable, I am quite new to SE

Comment: Actually I think there is no device meeting your requirements there is many devices without API like [Charger Doctor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1852) but if your main requirement is API I can't recommend you anything at this moment.

Comment: That is not possible (at least not in the strict sense it is asked for). An USB port has a certain specified output voltage that is not subject to negotiation or configuration.

Comment: Apart from expensive USB-controllable lab-grade test equipment you may not find this.  You could perhaps build something with some sort of adjustable voltage regulator, a digital potentiometer, and USB-interfaced microcontroller.  Or perhaps with extreme care, that USB MCU implementing the feedback loop of a switching regulator.  But it's not easy to make a regulator whose output voltage can adjust all the way up to its input voltage under load, and USB VBus may not be quite 5v under load anyway.

Comment: Maybe you could get a USB voltage regulator circuit board, controller by USB.  However, the IEEE USB specs have clearly stated what the voltage must be coming out of the USB port.